# When will Stanford Core NLP version 3.9.0 be on Maven Central?

Tags: stanford-nlp

The Stanford Core NLP says that version 3.9.0 is available but I can't see this on Maven Central yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3.9.0 is still in a beta phase, but we're working on putting it up on Maven Central very soon.  Hopefully early next week!

Update: Stanford CoreNLP 3.9.1 is now out on Maven Central !